# Requried is not defined, after migrating from Gulp 3 to 4

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I have a project which used Gulp 3 + Node 11 (The project is AngularJS with the basic webpack + babel etc ...).

The need arose to migrate to Gulp 4 + Node 12. I changed the syntax from Gulp 3 to 4, the command "gulp build" is running, the console appears that everything is ok.

But when I try to access the application it says that:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at eval (eval at globalEval (jquery.js:2)
```

This error is repeated with other libs as well.

Below a part of my gulp.js, the calls part, probably the error is here. I think I'm getting complicated in this business of having to force sync on gulp 4, which I didn't have on Gulp 3.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var simplevars = require('postcss-simple-vars');
var nested = require('postcss-nested');
var mqPacker = require('css-mqpacker');
var cssnano = require('cssnano');
var cssimport = require('postcss-import');
var usemin = require('gulp-usemin');
var fs = require('graceful-fs');
var open = require('open');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-clean-css');
// var gulpsync = require('gulp-sync')(gulp);
var express = require('express');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
// /* ES6 */
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var _ = require('lodash');
var through = require('through');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var fn = require('gulp-fn');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache');


function ErrorHandler() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    notify.onError({
        title: "Compile Error",
        message: "<%= error.message %>"
    }).apply(this, args);
    this.emit('end');
};

var envConfig = process.env.CONFIG || 'development';
var filename = envConfig + '.json';
var settings = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./config/' + filename, 'utf8'));
var isMinify = !!settings.minify;

settings.buildVersion = new Date().getTime();


var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var PATH = {
    js: {
        src: 'src/**/*.js',
        dest: 'build'
    },
    styles: {
        src: 'src/core/styles/common.css',
        srcWatch: 'src/**/*.css',
        dest: 'build/core/styles/'
    },
    images: {
        src: ['src/**/*.png', 'src/**/*.jpg', 'src/**/*.svg', 'src/**/*.pdf', 'src/**/*.ico'],
        dest: 'build'
    },
    fonts: {
        src: ['src/core/fonts/**/*.eot', 'src/core/fonts/**/*.ijmap', 'src/core/fonts/**/*.svg', 'src/core/fonts/**/*.ttf', 'src/core/fonts/**/*.woff', 'src/core/fonts/**/*.woff2'],
        dest: 'build'
    },
    fontsAwesome: {
        src: ['node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*.*'],
        dest: 'build/lib/fonts'
    },
    html: {
        src: 'src/**/*.html',
        dest: 'build'
    },
    usemin: {
        src: 'src/index.tmpl',
        dest: 'build'
    },
    windows: {
        srcPaste: '../../../inetpub/wwwroot/app',
        srcCopy: 'build/**/*.*',
        srcWebConfig: 'web.config'
    }
};

function replaceKeys() {
    return replace(/(@{2}[A-z,0-9]+)/g, function (key) {
        return settings[key.slice(2)];
    });
}

async function compileTemplateIndex() {
    gulp
        .src(PATH.usemin.src)
        .pipe(rename('index.html'))
        .pipe(replaceKeys())
        .pipe(usemin({
            assetsDir: '.',
            css: ['concat'],
            js: ['concat']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH.usemin.dest));
}

async function copyFonts() {
    gulp
        .src(PATH.fonts.src)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH.fonts.dest));
}

async function copyFontsAwesome() {
    gulp
        .src(PATH.fontsAwesome.src)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH.fontsAwesome.dest));
}


async function copyImages(done) {
    gulp
        .src(PATH.images.src)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH.images.dest));

    done()
}

async function copyImagesUI() {
    gulp
        .src('bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/base/images/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/lib/css/images'));
}


async function compileHtml() {
    return gulp.src(PATH.html.src)
        .pipe(replaceKeys())
        .pipe(templateCache({
            standalone: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH.html.dest));
}

async function compilePostCss() {
    var processors = [
        cssimport,
        simplevars,
        nested,
        mqPacker,
        autoprefixer
    ];

    if ( isMinify ) processors.push(cssnano({
        discardComments: {
            removeAll: true
        },
        zindex: false
    }));

    return gulp
        .src(PATH.styles.src)
        .pipe(postcss(processors))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH.styles.dest));
}

function transformKeys(file) {
    var data = '';

    return through(write, end);

    function write(buf) {
        data += buf
    }

    function end() {
        data = data.replace(/(@{2}[A-z,0-9]+)/g, function (key) {
            return settings[key.slice(2)];
        })
        this.queue(data);
        this.queue(null);
    }
}

async function compileEs6() {
    compileEs6_Bundle(false, './src/app.js', 'app.js');
    // compileEs6_Bundle(false, './src/components/components.module.js', 'components.js');
    // compileEs6_Bundle(false, './src/modules/modules.module.js', 'modules.js');
}

function compileEs6_watch() {
    compileEs6_Bundle(true, './src/app.js', 'app.js');
    // compileEs6_Bundle(true, './src/components/components.module.js', 'components.js');
    // compileEs6_Bundle(true, './src/modules/modules.module.js', 'modules.js');
}

function compileEs6_Bundle(watch, src, dest) {
    var bro;
    var src = src || './src/app.js';
    var dest = dest || 'app.js';

    if (watch) {

        livereload.listen();
        bro = watchify(browserify(_.assign(watchify.args, {
            entries: [src],
            debug: true
        })));
        bro.on('update', function (file) {
            console.log(file + ' changed');
            rebundle(bro);
        });
    } else {

        bro = browserify(src, {
            debug: true
        });
    }

    bro.transform(babelify.configure({
        compact: false,
        presets: ['@babel/env'],

    }));
    bro.transform(transformKeys);

    function rebundle(bundler) {
        return bundler.bundle()
            .on('error', ErrorHandler)
            .pipe(source(dest))
            .pipe(buffer())
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init({
                loadMaps: true
            }))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
            .pipe(gulpif(isMinify,
                uglify({
                    mangle: false
                })
            ))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'))
            .pipe(gulpif(watch, fn(
                function () {
                    livereload.reload();
                    openServer();
                }
            )));
    }

    return rebundle(bro);
}

async function watch() {
    livereload.listen();

    function livereloadNotify(e) {
        livereload.changed(e.path);
    }

    var onChanged = _.debounce(livereloadNotify, 600);

    /* listen js files */
    compileEs6_watch();

    gulp.watch(PATH.images.src, gulp.series(['copy-images'])).on('change', onChanged);
    gulp.watch(PATH.styles.srcWatch, gulp.series(['postcss'])).on('change', onChanged);
    gulp.watch(PATH.html.src, gulp.series(['html'])).on('change', onChanged);
    gulp.watch(PATH.usemin.src, gulp.series(['compile-template-index'])).on('change', onChanged);
}

async function webserver() {
    var app = express();

    app.use(express.static('build'));


    var server = app.listen(PORT, function () {
        console.log('Listening on port %d', PORT);
    });


    app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/build/index.html');
    });


}

function openServer() {
    //open('http://localhost:'+ PORT +'/');
    //openServer = function () {};
}

function copyFilesToBuildFolder() {
    function rmDir(dirPath) {
        try { var files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath); }
        catch(e) { return; }
        if (files.length > 0){
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var filePath = dirPath + '/' + files[i];
                if (fs.statSync(filePath).isFile()){
                    fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
                } else {
                    rmDir(filePath);
                }
            }
        }
        fs.rmdirSync(dirPath);
    }

    rmDir(PATH.windows.srcPaste);

    gulp
        .src(PATH.windows.srcCopy)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH.windows.srcPaste));

    gulp
        .src(PATH.windows.srcWebConfig)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(PATH.windows.srcPaste));
}

gulp.task('compile-es6', compileEs6);
gulp.task('compile-template-index', compileTemplateIndex);
gulp.task('copy-images', copyImages);
gulp.task('copy-fonts', copyFonts);
gulp.task('copy-fonts-awesome', copyFontsAwesome);
gulp.task('copy-images-ui', copyImagesUI);
gulp.task('html', compileHtml);
gulp.task('postcss', compilePostCss);
gulp.task('watch', watch);
gulp.task('server', webserver);
gulp.task('copy-files-to-build-folder', copyFilesToBuildFolder);

gulp.task('build', gulp.series(['copy-fonts','copy-fonts-awesome','copy-images-ui','postcss','copy-images','compile-template-index','html','compile-es6']));
gulp.task('serve', gulp.series(['build','server','watch']));
// gulp.task('build-sv-windows', gulpsync.sync(['build', 'copy-files-to-build-folder']));
```